# Which library - std::chrono::system_clock

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Which .dll file contains "std::chrono::system_clock" method?

I can't find any useful information in the documentation.

EDIT:
 I want to create my own version of the function, so I wanna rebuild the file and replace it in the import table of my own application

Comment: do you mean which header? which documentation are you using? something that doesnt mention in what header you can find it should not call itself "documentation"

Comment: I think it's in `msvcpNNN.dll` (where "NNN" is the version number of the VC++ redistributable). Why on earth would you ever want to know that though?

Comment: @NikosC. I want to create my own version of the function, so I wanna rebuild the file and replace it in the import table of my own application

Comment: If you look in chrono (in the 2019 version at least) then the code is inlined there so it likely won't be an import you can override. You can just copy and modify the code from there.

Comment: @Rup so could you tell me what exactly i have to do if i wanna change the system_clock function for my already compiled .dll?

Comment: You probably can't: it'll likely be inlined in the compiled code. You might get lucky: try looking at the DLL's imports (e.g. Dependency Walker, or the 'dumpbin /imports' command line tool) and see if system_clock is there, but I'd guess it won't be. You can disassemble the DLL e.g. with IDA Pro (there's a freeware version) and try and find the part of the binary you'll need to modify, which will be much easier if you have debug symbols for this DLL.

Comment: I think you would have to edit the chrono header and rebuild your dll. For me the header is at: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\include` however I am likely a few builds behind since I have not used VS recently on the home laptop.

Comment: @drescherjm so you don't think it's possible without rebuild my .dll, right? The case is I don't have the source code

Comment: Try the advice that @Rup gave before my post. I believe that is the only chance for it to work without rebuilding.

Comment: @drescherjm ine the import table I can only see .dll files like: USER32.dll, etc. There's many of them. Do you think it's inside one of them? I can't see msvcpXXX.dll though

Comment: This is not going to work very well. Why do you want to selectively replace parts of your toolchain's standard library implementation?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I need to replace the function I mentioned previously to return my own value. For testing purposes

Comment: No, that's what you think you should do. _Why_ do you think you need to do it this way? I can assure you, you're going down the wrong route for whatever your goal is. If you want to mock time functions, why not simply do that in your code in the usual manner?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I just want to do that if it is possible. Knowledge over rules

Comment: If you look at chrono you can see that it calls _Xtime_get_ticks(), which is exported by msvcp140.dll, if you can override that. (The XXX was meant as a version number, not literally Xs.) But if you don't have an msvcp* import then again it will be compiled into the DLL and not easily modifiable, although you can follow that to a CRT call and ultimately a Windows system call if you need to. But I agree this is the wrong way to go about testing your own code: you should mock it, or provide a way to override the time for testing. You should try and get hold of the source code.

Comment: BTW std::chrono::system_clock is not a "method"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sure, I meant now()

Comment: it looks like it's compiled into .dll, so I can't do this that way. Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to `#include <chrono>`. No further deployment needed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, without knowing your actual goal ("knowledge over rules", you said) it is impossible to tell you the right way to achieve it. I can only tell you that this is not it.

---

> I just want to do that if it is possible

For some value of possible, maybe.

It's possible that the code for this type is defined right there in the header, rather than built into the runtime. So, you would only "need" to modify the header. But then what about the rest of the runtime that expects the type to look a certain way? You've just violated the one-definition rule at the first hurdle.

It should go without saying:

### DO NOT DO THIS.

Your program has undefined behaviour when you modify the standard library, even if you can somehow manage to get enough controls of your implementation's internals to make it work without crashing and/or catching fire.

To do this "properly" you would have to fork and rebuild the entire standard library implementation so that its contents are consistent. Good luck with that.

---

Instead, if you want to use a type that looks like `std::chrono::system_clock` (it is *not* a "method", or member function — it is a class) but acts differently, *then define such a type yourself in your own namespace*.

People have been doing this, when mocking implementation functions, for many years. Your unit testing framework should come with some *documentation* that teaches you how to mock functionality successfully and reliably.